# SQL Server - SUM() and Group() Records based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by, count

In my gaming application, I have teams and each team can have any number of players; if a player participates in a match, I am giving him 5 points. Each time the player participates in a match, he will get 5 points added to his count.

My stored procedure takes `TeamId` as the input parameter.

Now I want to calculate the total participation points each team has got by month, but here the participation points each player has scored should be added to the last month in which the player has played the match.

Let's say `Team1` has `Player1` and `Player1` has played total of 4 matches, 1 match in 04/2020, 2 matches in 06/2020 and 1 match in 08/2020, here for playing 4 matches `Player1` of `Team1` got 20 participation points and the last match Player1 played is in 08/2020 so all the 20 points should be added to 08/2020 for Team1

In the player table across each Player I have a [TotalMatchesPlayed] by each player, [TotalMatchesPlayed] * 5 will give me the [TotalParticipationPoints] for each player.

This should repeat for all the players in the Team.

```
    SELECT SUM(ISNULL(P.[TotalMatchesPlayed], 0) * 5) AS [ParticipationPoints], CAST(MONTH(PA.[ActivityDate]) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [Month], CAST(YEAR(PA.[ActivityDate]) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Year] FROM [TeamPlayer] TP
INNER JOIN dbo.[Player] P
ON TP.[PlayerId] = P.[PlayerId]
INNER JOIN dbo.[PlayerActivity] PA
ON PA.[PlayerId] = P.[PlayerId] AND PA.[PlayerActivityTyepId] = 14
WHERE TP.[TeamId] = 45
GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(PA.[ActivityDate]) AS VARCHAR(2)), CAST(YEAR(PA.[ActivityDate]) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

My issue with this query is [PlayerActivity] table has a row each time a player participates in a match, now I want to take only the latest date and add all the participation points to that month and year which i am not able to achieve.

My sample output should be as below

```
ParticipationPoints | Month |  Year
        5                06     2020
       10                11     2020
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE TeamPlayer (
    TeamPlayerID int,
    PlayerId int,
    TeamId INT
);

INSERT INTO TeamPlayer VALUES (1, 101, 45)
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer VALUES (2, 104, 19)
INSERT INTO TeamPlayer VALUES (3, 108, 45)

CREATE TABLE Player (
    PlayerID int,
    FirstName VARCHAR(1000),
    LastName VARCHAR(1000),
    [TotalMatchesPlayed] INT
);

INSERT INTO Player VALUES (101, 'Joe', 'Abbey', 2)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (102, 'Vince', 'Abbott', 3)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (103, 'Duke', 'Abbruzzi', 7)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (104, 'Kamlesh', 'Abu', 9)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (105, 'Evika', 'Abram', 0)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (106, 'Prince', 'Subtle', 2)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (107, 'Dick', 'Absher', 1)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (108, 'George', 'Abrell', 1)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (109, 'William', 'Peck', 2)
INSERT INTO Player VALUES (110, 'Aaron', 'Adams', 0)

CREATE TABLE PlayerActivity (
    PlayerActivityId int,
    PlayerId int,
    PlayerActivityTyepId INT,
    ActivityDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO PlayerActivity VALUES (1, 101, 14, '2020-04-21')
INSERT INTO PlayerActivity VALUES (2, 108, 14, '2020-06-17')
INSERT INTO PlayerActivity VALUES (3, 101, 14, '2020-11-24')
```

Sample table designs and sample data in the below link with my query.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/870f92/1

To reiterate once again, If a player in a team has played multiple matches lets say 6, i need to add 6*5 = 30 points to the month in which he played his last match.

Comment: Fiddles should compliment a question, not be required for us to obtain the sample data.

Comment: @Larnu sorry Larnu, i did not get what you are trying to convey.. anything wrong in what i posted ?

Comment: You just posted a link, when the DDL and DML should be in the question as well.

Comment: will correct it next time onwards, this is the 1st time i used a fiddle

Comment: The sample output does not match the actual activity dates. e.g., there is no month 03 or 05 but there are months not listed as result. Either I did not understand your question or the example is wrong.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes The sample output i posted is just random data, just to specify how the output should look like... you can refer this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4aca64/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution uses a subquery that determines the last activity date for each player

```sql
SELECT
    PlayerId,
    MAX(ActivityDate) AS LastDate
FROM
    dbo.PlayerActivity
WHERE PlayerActivityTyepId = 14
GROUP BY PlayerId
```

The main query uses a GROUP BY as well to aggregate the results per team and year/month. The trick is done in a CASE expression. Here I compare the actual activity date with the last one determined by the subquery.  The points get only attributed on the last activity and otherwise 0.

```sql
SELECT
    TP.TeamId,
    SUM(
        CASE
           WHEN PA.ActivityDate = X.LastDate
           THEN P.TotalMatchesPlayed * 5
           ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS ParticipationPoints,
    RIGHT(CAST(100+MONTH(PA.ActivityDate) AS VARCHAR(3)), 2) AS [Month],
    CAST(YEAR(PA.ActivityDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Year]
FROM
    dbo.TeamPlayer TP
    INNER JOIN dbo.Player P
        ON TP.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
    INNER JOIN dbo.PlayerActivity PA
        ON PA.PlayerId = P.PlayerId AND PA.PlayerActivityTyepId = 14
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            PlayerId,
            MAX(ActivityDate) AS LastDate
        FROM
            dbo.PlayerActivity
        WHERE PlayerActivityTyepId = 14
        GROUP BY PlayerId
    ) AS X
        ON X.PlayerId = P.PlayerId
WHERE TP.TeamId = 45
GROUP BY
    TP.TeamId, YEAR(PA.ActivityDate), MONTH(PA.ActivityDate)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/41766/28/0

Note that I am assuming that there is only one activity per day per player. If there are more, the points will be summed up repeatedly. If the `PlayerActivityId` values are strictly inserted in ascending order, you can fix this by working the with `MAX(PlayerActivityId)` instead of `MAX(ActivityDate)`.

To get the month with two digits I first calculate month+100 and convert this to `VARCHAR(3)`. This yields `'104'` for April. Then I get the result by returning the last two characters with the `RIGHT` function. Of course, you could use proper formatting functions, but I was to lazy to look up the right functions and formats to use.

Comment: As per my initial testing the above query is working great but still need to test different scenarios, I have more than 1 activity per day and i think MAX(ActivityDate) should work as i capture Date by minutes and seconds as well and i did not post minutes and seconds in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select year(activitydate) as yyyy, month(activitydate) as mm, 
    sum(cnt) * 5 as partitionpoints
from (
    select pa.*, 
        count(*) over(partition by playerid) cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by playerid order by activitydate desc) rn
    from playeractivity pa
) t
where rn = 1
group by year(activitydate), month(activitydate)
order by yyyy, mm
```

The subquery computes the total count of activities per player, and ranks each player's records from the newest to the oldest. The outer query filters on the newest record, aggregates by year and month and does the computation.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb84c26b5b58c22432d0752528f7fde9)**:

```
yyyy | mm | partitionpoints
---: | -: | --------------:
2020 |  6 |               5
2020 | 11 |              10
```

Note that we can get this result by looking only at the activities table. It does not look like we need the teams table, nor the player table.